# Fitting two lines in ggplot scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have made a plot in ggplot2 using geom_point.  I want to fit a regression line to the infected and uninfected expression values, denoted as y and n respectively.  How can I do that?

```
#plotting
p = ggplot(oas, aes(x=hpi,y=expression, color = infection_status) ) +
  geom_point()
p + labs(x = "Hours post infection", y = "Expression (log2cpm +1)", colour = "Infected?")
```

[image]

The data frame used to make the plot:

```
> print(oas)
            expression hpi infection_status
SRR1346026 -1.99296894   4                N
SRR1346027 -2.73036339   4                Y
SRR1346028 -2.09282698   4                Y
SRR1346029 -3.20461929   4                Y
SRR1346030 -2.17659914   6                N
SRR1346031 -0.79651276   6                Y
SRR1346032  0.07630312   6                Y
SRR1346033 -2.16659057   6                Y
SRR1346034 -1.60442152  12                N
SRR1346035  1.77516608  12                Y
SRR1346036  3.37072286  12                Y
SRR1346037 -1.03317733  24                N
SRR1346038  6.20459628  24                Y
SRR1346039  7.38838203  24                Y
SRR1346040  5.64524296  24                Y
SRR1346041 -2.61149329  48                N
SRR1346042 -0.62253394  48                N
SRR1346043 -1.22872678  48                N
SRR1346044  3.48661571  48                Y
SRR1346045  5.14172576  48                Y
SRR1346046  8.00577520  48                Y
SRR1346047  8.78170903  48                Y
SRR1346049 -0.05784844  72                N
SRR1346048 -1.30151097  72                N
SRR1346050  8.77407666  72                Y
SRR1346051  9.18594576  72                Y
SRR1346052  8.76202212  72                Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_smooth`. Simply use this line:

```
p +  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr) ## for getting stat_regline_equation

p = ggplot(oas, aes(x=hpi,y=expression, color = infection_status) ) + geom_point()

p + labs(x = "Hours post infection", y = "Expression (log2cpm +1)") + stat_smooth(se=FALSE,aes(color = infection_status), method = "lm") + stat_regline_equation()
```

**output**:
[image]